# How to add password to my zip batch?

Tags: batch-file, password-protection, 7zip

```
for /d %%X in (*) do (for /d %%a in (%%X) do ( "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%%X.zip" ".\%%a\" ))
```

This is what I use right now 
I want to add password to it
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you type

```
7z
```

It will display all the switches.  The one you are looking for is -p

```
for /d %%X in (*) do (for /d %%a in (%%X) do ( "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -ppassword -tzip "%%X.zip" ".\%%a\" ))
```